# is it possible to have lists with the maximum number of common integers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list containing several lists of integers and I would like to find the lists having the maximum of common elements.

I tried to use the intersection, but it returns an empty set, since here the intersection concerns the common elements of *all* the lists found in my list.
I would like my code to show me the lists having the common integer number that I want. If I want, for example, the lists having 3 integers in common, that it displays the lists in question to me.
I have searched a lot on the net but I can only find reasoning to determine if two lists are identical or not.

Here is the code for intersection:

```
import string
list = [[3,5,9], [4,6,6], [4,7], [2,7], [2,1,4,5], [1,2,4,6], [3,3], [3,3], [3,2,1], [3,2]]
result = set.intersection(*map(set,list))
print(result)
```

Here is the result:

```
set()
```

but what I want is:

```
[2,1,4,5],[1,2,4,6]
```

Comment: explain, why number `5` should be in the final sublist `[2,1,4,5]`

Comment: Please explain your desired output, I am getting that the sublists with the most common integers are [1,2,4,6] and [3,2,1]

Comment: what do you mean by "maximum number of common integers", I would have assumed that meant the sets with the greatest number of duplicates but from your desired output it appears to be the sets with the greatest number of unique integers.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest i'm just  displaying the lists that have the highest number of common integers. As you can notice 1,2 and 4 come back in the 2 lists; what makes a total of 3 common elements.

Comment: @no_hex it's true that they have 1 and 2 in common but that only makes 2 elements . But the lists [2,1,4,5] and [1,2,4,6] have up to 3 elements in common, that's why these are the 2 lists i'm displaying

Comment: @Pioneer_11 yes that's what i want

Comment: @Lea ok that makes more sense. FYI in cases like this it's most common to use sets and refer to things as "elements"

Comment: @Lea you are on the right track with `intersection` but the syntax is `x.intersection(y)` where `x` and `y` are sets. I'll have to have a bit more of a think because at the moment all I can think to do is iterate performing set intersection between all pairs of sets and checking the length of the intersection. That approach would work but would also be extremely slow as it would be O(n^2) and set operations are relatively expensive. Given you're only working with integers I suspect there are some very substantial optimisations that could be made.

Comment: @Lea btw would [3, 3, 2, 1] and [4, 3, 3, 2] be considered to have two elements in common or three? sets don't permit duplicates so if the answer is three then the solution is going to be significantly more complex.

Comment: @Pioneer_11 [3, 3, 2, 1] and [4, 3, 3, 2] have 2 elements in common

Comment: @Pioneer_11 i work with a computer with a high capacity computer so the heaviness of the program will in no way bother me. The goal is to have firstly a good approach and i will optimize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First incorrect answer (misunderstanding of requirements)

```py
data = [[3, 5, 9], [4, 6, 6], [4, 7], [2, 7], [2, 1, 4, 5], [1, 2, 4, 6], [3, 3], [3, 3], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2]]

max_unique_elements = 0
holding = []
for data_list in data:
    unique_elements = len(set(data_list))

    if unique_elements > max_unique_elements:
        holding = [data_list]
        max_unique_elements = unique_elements

    elif unique_elements == max_unique_elements:
        holding.append(data_list)

print(holding)
```

Second (I believe) correct answer. Please note that this will not be optimal and as noted in comments will give incorrect answer if two or more sets have the maximum intersection (greatest number of common elements). Also due to the method using sets only one occurrence of each element will be printed e.g. [2, 3, 3, 4, 6] will be output as [3, 2, 4, 6] (order not preserved). I will fix these problems as soon as I have time but I am on holiday at the moment and this should give you the gist of how to solve this problem.

```
data = [[3, 5, 9], [4, 6, 6], [4, 7], [2, 7], [2, 1, 4, 5], [1, 2, 4, 6], [3, 3], [3, 3], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2]]
# set default to fist element of first list
most_common_count = 0
max_intersection = 0
sets_with_max_intersection = []

# sets remove any duplicates, as duplicates only count once
# (e.g. [4, 6, 6] and [6, 2, 6] only have one element in common)
# this makes processing easier
data_sets = [set(data_list) for data_list in data]

# count the number of sets which each element occurs in
for index, data_set_1 in enumerate(data_sets):
    for data_set_2 in data_sets[index + 1:]:
        union_result = data_set_1.intersection(data_set_2)

        # new greatest union found
        if len(union_result) > max_intersection:
            max_intersection = len(union_result)
            sets_with_max_intersection = [data_set_1, data_set_2]

        # equal length to max union assume part of same group and add
        # note: will give erroneous result if two or groups of sets
        # have the same number of elements in common
        elif len(union_result) == max_intersection:
            if data_set_1 not in sets_with_max_intersection:
                sets_with_max_intersection.append(data_set_1)
            if data_set_2 not in sets_with_max_intersection:
                sets_with_max_intersection.append(data_set_2)

print(max_intersection)
print(sets_with_max_intersection)
```

Comment: as an FYI in python `list(x)` turns `x` into a `list` so while it is possible it's a bad idea to use `list` as a variable name

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. it works but only for this case. if i eliminate for example the list [2,1,4,5] and i add another list such as [4,6,6], instead of giving me new list of element having the highest number common integer it keeps showing me [1,2,4,6] instead of [4,6,6].

Comment: @Lea, but `[4,6,6]` has the same number of common integers as `[3, 5, 9]`, and `[1,2,4,6]` has more common numbers than `[4,6,6]`

Comment: here are for example 2 lists [1,4,3] and [1,8,9] what i call common elements is the fact that 1 is both on the first and on the second list.

Comment: now suppose we have 3 lists [1,4,3], [1,8,9] et [1,9,10].  What i call the lists having the maximun of common elements it is according to this reasonning:  the 3 lists have the number 1 in common . The lists [1,8,9] and [1,9,10] have 1 and 9 which appear on both lists. Therefore the lists having the maximun of common elements on the 3 lists are [1,8,9] and [1,9,10]

Comment: @Pioneer_11,  sorry for the latency of the response i was looking for a slightly clearer example to illustrate my point.

Comment: @Lea would [4, 6, 6] and [6, 2, 6] be considered to have two elements in common or one?

Comment: @Lea Also how much data are you looking at dealing with? I can think of a few ways of solving this but none which are faster than O(n2) so if you've got a lot of lists then that'll be a big problem

Comment: @Pioneer_11 [4,6,6] and [6,2,6] have one element in common

Comment: @Pioneer_11 70 maximum lists. for the moment i just want to find a way to solve the problem, no matter how complex. So even O(n2) will be welcome.

Comment: @Pioneer_11 thank's so much!It's working !

Answer (score 0):

What you want is filtering the pairs of lists based on the condition of having 3 items in the intersection.

You can get all the pairs by using [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) and filter them with a [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp):

```
import string
from itertools import combinations

list_ = [[3,5,9], [4,6,6], [4,7], [2,7], [2,1,4,5], [1,2,4,6], [3,3], [3,3], [3,2,1], [3,2]]

print([c for  c in combinations(list_, r=2) if len(set(c[0]) & set(c[1])) == 3])
```

The output is as requested:

```
[([2, 1, 4, 5], [1, 2, 4, 6])]
```

Comment: thank's for your answer . The code works fine but onlyfor this particular case. If i modify the list slightly it returns me an empty list. Thanks for the links, i'll take a closer look.

Comment: @Lea the code looks for length 3 in 2 lists, you can modify those numbers to adapt it to your needs